# serialize an array of Players in java

Tags: java, arrays, serialization

I would like to implement a Save and Load option to my little game. I have an `array` of Players, each Player has a few attributes such as an `array` of Ships and a Map (2-D `array`) and stuff... I know how to save the array to a `.ser` but what if I want to save, when Player #3 (`players[2]`) is in charge. How do the program know that after loading the data that it is his turn? Thanks in advance, I hope you understand what I mean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is to encapsulate the list of players inside another object (let's say `Players`) and include a field that says which player's turn it is:

```
public class Players {
    private int currentPlayerIndex = 0;
    private List<Player> players;

    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of ways.
You can use Players class as shown above.
You can add attribute isInCharge to the Player class.
You can use a list or map with your own key/index convention to define players.